# Ngx translate with shared/lazy loading modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular7, ngx-translate

Probably one of the most common questions, while the [documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#1-import-the-translatemodule) and some [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992232/ngx-translate-not-showing-any-text-in-lazy-loaded-module) I found try to clear up things for me, yet I am still not sure how to fix this.

So this is my structure:

[image]

- App module is of course the main module that is bootstrapped
- Countryselector module: takes care of loading the default country(based on IP) and takes care of deciding what language to use based on the browser. It basically is the core functionality of deciding what country/language is used + it contains a dropdown for a user to change the country/language.
- Checkout module, selection module, payment module are all lazy-loaded with routing.

**AppModule**

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ContrySelectorModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  export class AppModule { }
```

**CountrySelectorModule**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [CountryselectorComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    CountryselectorComponent
  ]
})
export class ContrySelectorModule { }
```

**Selection module:**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SelectionComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SelectionRoutingModule,
    UspblockModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({//or forRoot, no idea how to configure this
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }})
  ],
})
export class SelectionModule { }
```

Now the problem is that I don't want to do the language configuration again within the lazy-loaded modules, because the country selector module already takes care of this. I am not sure now how to correctly configure the lazy-loaded modules (and actually not sure if countrySelectorModule is done correctly). Using the [standard github documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#1-import-the-translatemodule) I was not able to pull this off. I've tried messing around with `.forChild()` but no luck so far.

Do I need a share module? Do I need to import countrySelectorModule everywhere (not preferred)? Custom loader? t.b.h. I have no idea and the documentation is a bit short for more advanced scenarios.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

1. Create a `SharedModule`, with below code

**SharedModule**

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    },
    isolate: false
}),
  ],
  exports: [TranslateModule],
})
export class SharedModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ShoppingCartService, AccountService]
    }
  }
}
```

So this makes sure that for every module that imports `SharedModule`, `TranslateModule` will use the same configuration. Make sure to export it. The `forRoot()` also solved making sure that `ShoppingCartService` and `AccountService` are only one instance and not every lazy-module creating a separate service.

3. Change AppModule:

**AppModule**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate : false
    }),
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    ContrySelectorModule,
    
  ],
  providers: [    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Since `AppModule` is your main entry point, do the `forRoot()` call here to `TranslateModule` and the `SharedModule`.

3. Any lazy loaded module just has to import `SharedModule` without any method calls. Also `CountrySelectorModule` in my example has to just import `SharedModule` and nothing else.

Comment: Your "ContrySelectorModule" is not lazy loaded. You import your module in app.module, so there is no lazy loading feature possible. The solution for the TranslateModule is not working, if you have REAL lazy loading modules.

Comment: `CountrySelectorModule` is part of the main page and therefor imported in the `AppModule`. I'm quite sure that this setup works for lazy-loaded modules, true that the examples is perhaps a bit off.

Comment: Got a other solution. TranslateModule.forRoot in app.module, the shared module is only imported in the lazy loaded modules and shared.module need TranslateModule.forChild({extend:true})

Comment: Not sure what `extended` does but the rest is similar to my code.

Comment: Using Angular 13+: Instead of doing `static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders { ... }`, use the following: `static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<AppModule> { ... }`

Comment: @CularBytes could you pls create your implementation in stackblitz? am also working on same task, it would help me if provide your stackblitz implementation . Thanks :)